# insert inline date pickerView cell - swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I'm trying to implement inline date picker view using [this](https://github.com/DylanVann/DatePickerCell) class  , here is the code as shown in the example on this class :

```
 var cells:NSMutableArray = []
let datePickerCell = DatePickerCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)

  //in ViewDidLoad : 

   cells = [datePickerCell]


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // Get the correct height if the cell is a DatePickerCell.
    let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let datePickerCell = cell as? DatePickerCell {
        return datePickerCell.datePickerHeight()
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Deselect automatically if the cell is a DatePickerCell.
    let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    if let datePickerCell = cell as? DatePickerCell {
        datePickerCell.selectedInTableView(tableView)
        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }


}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cells.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    return cells[indexPath.row] as! UITableViewCell
}
```

I wanted to insert rows when click on button , using this code :

```
 func insert() {
    cells.addObject(datePickerCell)


    let insertionIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: cells.count - 1, inSection: 0)

    tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([insertionIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

what I get is empty cells with no date picker view , I also tried to add another datePickerCell to cells array :

```
cells = [datePickerCell , datePickerCell]
```

the same thing happens , nothing but empty cell

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifdtK.png) showing the empty cells and only one date picker view

any help ?

Comment: In library it is like cells = [[datePickerCell]] so change then try. you r missing one bracket

Comment: even if I did this cells = [[datePickerCell] , [datePickerCell]] , the cells are still empty

Comment: Ok, I will make one demo for you. You want datepicker in every cell, Right?

Comment: yes , I want to add new cell with datePicker every time I click on button.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and reply you @ienamo

Comment: Its my pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace your function of button with

```
func insert() {
        let datePickerCell = DatePickerCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cells.addObject(datePickerCell)
               self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: cells.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```